Bevel along curve becomes a flat shape
I'm running Blender 4.3.1 on Windows 11.
I am making an exhaust for a laundry drier which I want to 3D print. I modelled a low poly shape which transforms from a cylinder into a flat shape and turns 90° along the way. I want to separate the part into two pieces (red and blue in the image below), connected with a rim on each part so I can glue both pieces together after printing.

I am trying to create the rim as demonstrated in the video by Jason Ferry
I created a curve named Trajectory as follows:

I have separated the edge loop from the separation plane using duplicate (shift-D) and separate selection (P)
Applied all modifiers
Applied rotations
Applied scale
Converted the mesh in a curve

I created another curve named Profile which represents the cross section of the rim.
For Trajectory:

I chose Geometry > Bevel under the Object Data Parameters
I selected the Profile curve under Object

expecting Profile to be extruded along Trajectory into a 3D rim.

Trajectory (white) and Profile (orange)

What I got instead is a flat line extruded along Trajectory. It looks like Profile is first scaled with scale factor 0 in Y-direction, which yields a flat racing track like shape.

If I select Geometry > Bevel > Round, everything works fine:

I also tried creating a different Bezier curve to be used as a trajectory, but the result remains the same.
Here is a link to the blender file: 

Solved it!
The Profile should not have been located at a node of the Trajectory, but at the global origin.
I still don't understand the logic of the result becoming flat, but it is working now.

(Using Blender 4.2.5)
The extruded profile must be built in the XY plane and centered at world origin:

